# How to fetch image from URL (HTTP) in c++?

Tags: c++, httpwebrequest

How can I fetch an image from a URL in c++ and store it on harddisk?
Thanks.

I am working in the openGL environment in c++ so that code is not related to my question.
All i want to do is fetch some image from a URL and store it on my hard disk.

Which is the Google Map static map API which i want to use to fetch the image and store.

Sample request URL would be:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false

Comment: Add the specifics of what u have and what u exactly want.

Comment: images are not a resource different from others that you can access trought http. You need a http client with a c++ interface to download it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ isn't PHP and has no means to do that itself. You'll have to use the platform API at least (to open a socket, which isn't a part of the C++ standard), and better yet, use a third-party library — for example, with Qt you could do that in a few lines.

Comment: whats QT? some API? can you provide few reference links? thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Paul: Qt is a universal cross-platform programming framework (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework) ). It has quite extensive API and it can do a lot more than just get an image and save it. It's very well documented and quite easy to use. The only drawback may be the library size, which is quite big — if it matters, I'd considered using libcURL too, as @Bruno suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library such as [libcURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/).